# How do I solicit more information from an answer when the question is locked?

Tags: support, comments, locked-posts

I'm seeing [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7910570/1525840) on SO and I feel that I'd need to post a comment to it with a relevant follow-up question. However, there's no link nor button to do that.

What do I do?

I could try to look up the user's other posts and write there but that's obviously **very, very bad** thing to do.

Comment: You can't comment because it's historically locked; there's content we don't want to lose, but the question is not on-topic. What follow-up were you hoping to ask?

Comment: That answer points to a Github project.  You could try contacting the author; there's a Contact link at the bottom of the Github page.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, I figured that's why I can't comment. I still want to. I wish to know how permanent the link doing the job is going to be. The one that the guy copied from and improved says that they want to get paid because "servers aren't cheap", so I figure - maybe the improver also needs to pay and will therefore turn the service down.

Comment: That doesn't really seem fitting for SO at all. @RobertHarvey is right, you should contact the maintainer elsewhere.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've followed his advice already. Even got an email address so a reply will be due soon. That should be the answer, in fact. As for on/off-topic, I'm not sure I agree that the post is off-topic (it's definitely useful and helpful), so my comment would be a nice contribution. However, I can imagine that I'm a bit biased on this so I'm prone to follow the community's opinion.   :)

Comment: My guess would be while it is useful, it really isn't a question. though, instead of closing, maybe it would have been better to edit it into a real question so we could have used it as a canonical dupe target.

Comment: The answerer has [a couple of other posts that appear to be on the same subject](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A11236+anyorigin); perhaps a comment under one of those would be appropriate?